# How do I hide a jquery dialog until content is retrieved?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button's onclick set to use the following function EditContact. This function sets up a jquery dialog, gets the data from the server and displays it. Everything works but I would like to get it to work a little better. Right now the empty dialog pops up for the time it takes the code to go and fetch the content from the server then the dialog populates with the content. My question is how can I get the dialog to not pop up until the content has been received.

```
function EditContact() {
        $('#editContactView').dialog({
            modal: true,
            width: 'auto',
            position: ['top', 'center'],
            resizable: false,
            autoOpen: false,
            open: function (event) {
                var szAction = "Content url for this example";
                $(this).load(szAction,
                        function (response, status, xhr) {
                            $('#editContactView').dialog('open');
                            return false;
                        });
            }
        });

        $('#editContactView').dialog('open');

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should be able to essentially turn what you have inside out and and open the dialog on $().load() completion. Something like this might do it:

```
function editContact() {
    var szAction = "Content url for this example";
    $(this).load(szAction, function (response, status, xhr) {
        $('#editContactView').dialog({
            modal: true,
            width: 'auto',
            position: ['top', 'center'],
            resizable: false
        });
    });
}
```

Edit:
Notice I removed the {autoOpen: false}. This will create it and open it in one shot after you receive the content.

Comment: I think this is close to what needs to be done but right now it is not working for me. I will post back when I get it working.

Comment: I think `$(this).load()` should actually be `$('#editContactView').load()` in this case.

Comment: I had a syntax error that was causing my problems, this solution worked. thanks for the input.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `.dialog('open')` twice: in the end of the code and in the callback for the loading.

As JavaScript is asynchronous, it runs the line `$('#editContactView').dialog('open');` in the end before the data is received.

Removing this line should solve the problem.

Comment: that was the first thing I tried and it did not work. Thanks for helping out.